# Python pandas apply function if a column value is not NULL

Tags: python, list, pandas, null, apply

I have a dataframe (in Python 2.7, pandas 0.15.0):

```
df=
       A    B               C
0    NaN   11             NaN
1    two  NaN  ['foo', 'bar']
2  three   33             NaN
```

I want to apply a simple function for rows that does not contain NULL values in a specific column. My function is as simple as possible:

```
def my_func(row):
    print row
```

And my apply code is the following:

```
df[['A','B']].apply(lambda x: my_func(x) if(pd.notnull(x[0])) else x, axis = 1)
```

It works perfectly. If I want to check column 'B' for NULL values the `pd.notnull()` works perfectly as well. But if I select column 'C' that contains list objects:

```
df[['A','C']].apply(lambda x: my_func(x) if(pd.notnull(x[1])) else x, axis = 1)
```

then I get the following error message: `ValueError: ('The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()', u'occurred at index 1')`

Does anybody know why `pd.notnull()` works only for integer and string columns but not for 'list columns'?

And is there a nicer way to check for NULL values in column 'C' instead of this:

```
df[['A','C']].apply(lambda x: my_func(x) if(str(x[1]) != 'nan') else x, axis = 1)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The problem is that `pd.notnull(['foo', 'bar'])` operates elementwise and returns `array([ True,  True], dtype=bool)`. Your if condition trys to convert that to a boolean, and that's when you get the exception.

To fix it, you could simply wrap the isnull statement with `np.all`:

```
df[['A','C']].apply(lambda x: my_func(x) if(np.all(pd.notnull(x[1]))) else x, axis = 1)
```

Now you'll see that `np.all(pd.notnull(['foo', 'bar']))` is indeed `True`.

Comment: note that `np.all([True, True])` will return `True`. I think that'll work for the OP.

Comment: @PaulH Thanks. I tried with `all` but neglected `np.all`. The problem is not with `[True, True]`, but rather with `False`. While `all(pd.notnull(None))` raises an error, `np.all(pd.notnull(None))` does not.

Comment: Thank you Korem, it works! What I wonder is that a single `pd.notnull(df['C'])` returns with `False, True, False` but not with `False, [True, True], False`.

Comment: @ragesz I don't know. You could ask a new question if you'd like.

Answer (score 21):

I had a column contained lists and `NaN`s. So, the next one worked for me.

```
df.C.map(lambda x: my_func(x) if type(x) == list else x)
```

Answer (score 6):

Also another way is to just use `row.notnull().all()` (without `numpy`), here is an example:

```
df.apply(lambda row: func1(row) if row.notnull().all() else func2(row), axis=1)
```

Here is a complete example on your df:

```
>>> d = {'A': [None, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [11, None, 33, 4], 'C': [None, ['a','b'], None, 4]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df
     A     B       C
0  NaN  11.0    None
1  2.0   NaN  [a, b]
2  3.0  33.0    None
3  4.0   4.0       4
>>> def func1(r):
...     return 'No'
...
>>> def func2(r):
...     return 'Yes'
...
>>> df.apply(lambda row: func1(row) if row.notnull().all() else func2(row), axis=1)
0    Yes
1    Yes
2    Yes
3     No
```

And a friendlier screenshot :-)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try...

```
df['a'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(',','\,') if x != None else x)
```

this example just adds an escape character to a comma if the value is not None

Comment: This code will return an error as NaN != None

Answer (score 1):

Add the Following IF condition which returns NONE when it's TRUE

```
def funtion_name(input):
    if (pd.isnull(input)==False)
        return np.NAN
     //Rest funtion code//
```

Answer (score 1):

The below will work for different data types.

```
df=

   col_1  col_2
0    1     NaN
1  three  seven
2   NaN    NaN
3  [4,5]    2
```

It can be done with map, for eg to replace NON-NULL values in `col_1`:

```
def my_func(n):
    return 'func'

df.loc[df['col_1'].notnull(), 'col_1'] = df['col_1'].map(my_func)
df =

    col_1  col_2
0    func   NaN
1    func   seven
2    NaN    NaN
3    func   func
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string and want to apply function like this example:
`'September 25, 2021'`

```
df['Year'] = df['date_added'].apply(lambda x : re.split(' |,', x)[-1] if isinstance(x, str) else np.nan)
df['Month'] = df['date_added'].apply(lambda x : re.split(' |,', x)[0] if isinstance(x, str) else np.nan )
```

You can apply this way and use `isinstance(x, str)` to avoid `NaN` or any other type, you can also use `type()` like this.

```
df['Year'] = df['date_added'].apply(lambda x : re.split(' |,', x)[-1] if type(x)==str else np.nan )
```