# Pandas apply to all values except missing

Tags: python, pandas, nan

Say I had a series such as:

> [1,2, NAN, 4]

If I did:

```
series.apply(lambda a: a+2)
```

I would get an error due to the NAN. Is there an elegant way to preserve the NANs while applying my change?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614465/python-pandas-apply-function-if-a-column-value-is-not-null

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this:

```
In [32]: s
Out[32]:
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    NaN
3    4.0
dtype: float64

In [33]: s.apply(lambda a: a+2 if pd.notnull(a) else a)
Out[33]:
0    3.0
1    4.0
2    NaN
3    6.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but what if they are strings? np.isnan("a") throws an error

Comment: for strings use pd.isna(a)