# Can't apply a function because I have NaN

Tags: python, dataframe, nan

I'm trying to change the date format to a column but I cant apply my function because I have NaN cells.

```
# change date format
def dmy_to_dmy(d):
    return datetime.strptime(d, '%d %B %Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

dates2['Dates_Reins'] = dates2['Dates_Reins'].apply(dmy_to_dmy)
```

My data looks like this:

```
46  9 September 2021
47  NaN
48  24 July 2021
49  28 September 2021
50  18 October 2021
51  8 January 2021
52  NaN
```

Thanks

Comment: put your code inside a try and capture an exception for the cases where you have a NaN

Comment: What would you want your function to return in the event that it finds a `NaN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options, ingoring the problem or detecting the problem. The first one is the easy one since you try and pass if it doesn't happen. The second one will detect the NaN

First solution

```
# change date format
def dmy_to_dmy(d):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(d, '%d %B %Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    except TypeError:
        return d
    
dates2['Dates_Reins'] = dates2['Dates_Reins'].apply(dmy_to_dmy)
```

Second solution

```
# change date format
def dmy_to_dmy(d):
    if d == np.nan:
        return d
    else:
        return datetime.strptime(d, '%d %B %Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    
dates2['Dates_Reins'] = dates2['Dates_Reins'].apply(dmy_to_dmy)
```

Since you haven't provided the data `d==np.nan` you have to find for yourself

Answer (score 0):

You can detect whether the input to your function is a `Nan` value and return it before you start to operate with it:

```
def dmy_to_dmy(d):
    if d == np.nan:
      return np.nan
    return datetime.strptime(d, '%d %B %Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: I get this error TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not float

Comment: @mvac Try converting d to string with `str(d)`

Answer (score 0):

You can either make your function ignore NaN:

```
def dmy_to_dmy(d):
    if isinstance(d, float) and np.isnan(d):
        return np.nan
        
    return datetime.strptime(d, '%d %B %Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

dates2['Dates_Reins'] = dates2['Dates_Reins'].apply(dmy_to_dmy)
```

Or, call your function on only the non-NaN values:

```
notna = dates2['Dates_Reins'].notna()
dates2['Dates_Reins'] = dates2.loc[notna, 'Dates_Reins'].apply(dmy_to_dmy)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dates2['Dates_Reins'].apply(lambda x: dmy_to_dmy(x) if x != np.nan else x)
```

Inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56589062/7509907

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a function [`to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) that can take a Series (or DataFrame column) as its first arg and allows values of type `str` in that object to be converted to dates, with NaN values handled in one of several ways.

Sample code:

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.Series(['9 September 2021', np.nan, '24 July 2021', '28 September 2021', '18 October 2021', '8 January 2021', np.nan], index=range(46,53)).to_frame()
df.columns = ['Dates_Reins']
print(df)

df['Dates_Reins'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates_Reins'], format='%d %B %Y', errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
print(df)
```

Input:

```
         Dates_Reins
46   9 September 2021
47                NaN
48       24 July 2021
49  28 September 2021
50    18 October 2021
51     8 January 2021
52                NaN
```

Output:

```
   Dates_Reins
46  09/09/2021
47         NaN
48  24/07/2021
49  28/09/2021
50  18/10/2021
51  08/01/2021
52         NaN
```

Passing `'coerce'` to the function using the `errors` arg allows conversion of all valid values that are of a supported type (including `str`) to be converted to type [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) using the specified `format` arg, with others set to NaN.

We can then use the [`Series.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) accessor to invoke [`Series.dt.strftime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and convert the non-NaN values back to values of type `str` using our specified format.

NOTE: We could alternatively pass `errors='ignore'` to `to_datetime()` which would cause values that can't be parsed as valid dates to be returned as is, but this would cause `Series.dt.strftime()` to fail.